# How to produced group barplot with different color codes?

Tags: r, rscript

I am trying to make grouped barplots with below formatted data. I wrote the below code but it is not serving my purpose

Data

```
data1 <- read.table(text="              NAS  AG   PT      ST
1kb_+/-TSS   1239 885   1232    952
1.5kb_+/-TSS 1440 1092  1467    1181
2kb_+/-TSS   1647 1248  1635    1398
2.5kb_+/-TSS 1839 1403  1794    1594", header=TRUE)
```

Code

```
data2=as.matrix(data1)
b<-barplot(data2, legend= rownames(data2), beside= TRUE,las=2,cex.axis=0.7,cex.names=0.7,ylim=c(0,3000), col=c("cornflowerblue","cornsilk4","red","orange"))
tx2 <- data2
text(b,tx2+10, as.character(tx2),pos = 3, cex = 0.5, col = "darkgreen")
```

Below is the image
[image]

I do not want to have the color combination like this I want the color for each group like NAS(shades of blue for each rows),AG(shades of cornsilk4, PT(shades of read), ST(shades of orange)

How shall I modify the code? So each category has lighter shades of the 4 colours I used in the main code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want different shades for each of the colors, you will have to create those colors your selves. Here's one such function that can calculate lighter colors

```
fadecolors <- function(colors, steps=4) {
    rr <- col2rgb(colors)
    unlist(Map(function(a) {
        rgb( seq(255, a[1],length.out=steps+1)[-1],
        seq(255,a[2],length.out=steps+1)[-1],
        seq(255,a[3],length.out=steps+1)[-1],
           maxColorValue=255)
    }, as.data.frame(rr)))
}

colors <- c("cornflowerblue","cornsilk4","red","orange")
barplot(data2, legend= rownames(data2), beside= TRUE,las=2,cex.axis=0.7,cex.names=0.7,ylim=c(0,3000), col=fadecolors(colors))
```

This results in

[image]

Basically the idea is to add a certain amount of white (in RGB scale) to each color. There are certainly more sophisticated ways to choose colors out there.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks this function is fine but the legend is not picking up for different color codes.

Comment: how will I also integrate the legends with each color code? The function is of great use. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `adjustcolor` does this also `barplot(data2, beside= TRUE, col = Vectorize(adjustcolor)(rep(colors, each = 4), alpha.f = c(.3,.6,.8,.9)))`

Comment: @vchris_ngs Adding `args.legend=list(fill=colors)` will return the solid colors for the groups. Not sure what you really want to put in the legend at this point.

Comment: @rawr good call on `adjustcolor`. That's a function I didn't know about.

Comment: thanks a lot @MrFlick and @rawr for the `adjustcolor` function. Infact it is doing the same thing. Great to learn a knew feature.

Comment: I guess putting legends at rownames will be difficult and confusing, I could not put all of them probably my dataframe is arranged in a different way, other wise I have to create count table for each I believe